# Django Media Files Not Showing

Tags: python, django, django-media

My Django files are loading after upload and are shown in the media folder, however I cannot access them at `localhost:<PORT>/media/<FILENAME._EXT>`. I've looked at several other answers on stackoverflow and they haven't worked. For example adding the `urlpatterns += static(...)`, having `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`.

When accessing: `http://localhost:8000/media/controller.gif`:

**Error:**

```
lightchan-backend-1   | Not Found: /media/controller.gif
lightchan-backend-1   | 2022-03-06 16:37:34,875 WARNING  Not Found: /media/controller.gif
```

In `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

In my `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
  path('comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.comment, name='comment'),
  path('comments/', views.comments, name='comments'),
  path('reply/<int:incoming_id>/', views.reply, name='reply')
]

# if settings.DEBUG is True:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: how are you defining BASE_DIR?

Comment: By the default: # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: and where is your settings.py file located? Can you `print(BASE_DIR)` to make sure you are using the correct path?